# how to parse the value from xml through xsl

Tags: xslt

```
<block4>
  <tag>
    <name>50K</name>
    <value>/001/002/300060000120135670
CREDIT AGRICOLE ASSET MANAGEMENT</value>
  </tag>
</block4>
```

I need to get output that looks like:

```
/001/002,/300060000120135670,CREDIT AGRICOLE ASSET MANAGEMENT
```

I have done like this in XSL, but I didn't get the output I wanted. Can anyone please give me some idea how I could get that output?

```
<xsl:for-each select ="block4/tag[name = '50K']">
  <xsl:value-of  select="
    concat(
      substring(value,1,8),
      (concat(substring(value,9,'&#13;'),',')),
      substring-after(value,'&#13;')
    )
  " />,<xsl:text/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: hi cody can you say what you have modified ..?? in that xsl please

Comment: i m recieving output like /001/002,CREDIT AGRICOLE ASSET MANAGEMENT  i m not recieving middle value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`concat` takes any number of arguments, no need to nest those calls. Besides, `substring` takes a beginning and an optional length, not a terminating character. Try something like this instead:

```
<xsl:for-each select ="block4/tag[name = '50K']">
  <xsl:value-of select="
    concat(
      substring(value, 1, 8), ',',
      substring(substring-before(value,'&#xA;'),9), ',',
      substring-after(value,'&#xA;')
    )
  " />,<xsl:text/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I've kept the final comma in, which is one of the many things you did not really specify.

Comment: <value>/001/002                                    /300060000120135670
CREDIT AGRICOLE ASSET MANAGEMENT                               </value>   christo if some times value comes like this means how can we get !! need same output only

Comment: As soulSurfer said, you really should consider `tokenize`. Your input is not useful XML, since it obviously puts different kinds of data into some formatted text filed and `tokenize` was made exactly for that.

Comment: thats okay !!! if two values are there means it was seperated by space means we are writing like in xsl that concating substring before space and substring after space like that three values were seperated by in between two space means how can we wright in xsl if you have an idea please let me know

Comment: @pubby and @Christopher Creutzig: **This is wrong.** Remember that new lines are normalized to `#xA;` in XML according to http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-line-ends

Comment: @ Christopher Creutzig please help me i have posted a question i was trying from so many days i dint find solution can you please give me some suggestions.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000029/fetching-data-from-xml-using-xslt

Comment: @user357812: Right, sorry. fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use XSLT 2.0 `tokenize()` function?
See [Here](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/05/07/tr.html)

Comment: off course we cant relay on that xml for every time it will keep on changing in that first 8 characters related to one column and from 9 char to first space related to second column and remaining belongs to third column

Comment: Tried parsing @pubby's comment and failed.