# fetching data from xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

having a xml with same tag names but for that tag names values were different , so we expecting an output like one by one transaction

```
<swift>
 <message>
 <block3>
    <tag>
       <name>32</name>
       <value>praveen</value>
    </tag>
    <tag>
       <name>42</name>
       <value>pubby</value>
   </tag>
</block3> 
<block4>
    <tag>
       <name>77</name>
       <value>pravz</value>
    </tag>
    <tag>
        <name>77</name>
        <value>pubbypravz</value>
    </tag>
    <tag>
        <name>76</name>
         <value>shanmu</value>
   </tag>
   </block4>
  </message>
</swift>
```

xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:template match="/">            
    <xsl:for-each select="swift/message">   

                  <xsl:for-each select ="block3/tag[name = '32']">
            <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
        </xsl:for-each>,<xsl:text/>

                    <xsl:for-each select ="block4/tag[name = '77']">
            <xsl:value-of select="value"/>,<xsl:text/>
        </xsl:for-each>

        </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
```

by this above xslt i have reached up to this

```
praveen,pravz,pubbypravz,
```

output needed:

```
 praveen,pravz

 praveen,pubbypravz
```

hope we need to set a loop for each time please guide me ...

Comment: you should provide a sample of your xml source and a sample of the xml output you would like to obtain to get some answers.

Comment: USD,EUR,DINAR                                                                                                                                                                         INR,EUR,DINAR ..........  required output

Comment: on what basis people voted negatively ...if they dint know the output for that please be clam dont make unneccessarily reduce my reputations

Comment: Say, you have 3 different states, each one occurring three times with 3 different currency values for each - how many lines of output do you expect? 3^3 = 27 ? What purpose for?

Comment: @doc brown for people understanding purpose i have written like that and that to i was very new to this site don mine

Comment: actually my problem is above one state which was repeated again "XXXX" so when if i m calling form my xslt means i m getting output like values of XXXX,XXXX,YYYY,ZZZZ but i dont want like that for example assume three bank names are there ... they are doing transaction XXXX was done two transactions at the same day so first i need to get XXXX first transaction with remaining banks and in next line i need XXXX second transaction with the same remaining banks

Comment: @user753335: I think one may solve these problem with XSLT, but I don't expect to see an elegant solution here.

Comment: nope @doc brown ...i dint receive any solution from any one ! i m asking you people how to write a logic in xslt ...i hope you understand my requirement if not please let me know i will explain you please help me boss i was trying from past two days

Comment: HELLO LET ME EXPLAIN ONCE AGAIN OF MY REQUIREMENT, THE ABOVE XML WHICH WAS RECEIVED FORMAT UNDER THAT YOU CAN SEE PARTICULAR ELEMENTS WHICH WERE MULTIPLE (xxxx) REMAINING ELEMENTS TAGS ARE BEEN GENERAL SO THEY WERE PROVIDE IN XML ONLY ONCE SO WE NEED BASE AN XSLT FOR ABOVE XML FOR EACH xxxx ELEMENT, SO HOW TO EXCUTE A LOGIC IN XSL PLEASE GIVE SOME SUGGESTIONS ...

Comment: @user753335: some hints to get better answers (edit your question above, don't post it as comment): 1. show us your xslt approach you have created so far. 2. Make your input data a complete XML file, so one can run your xslt against that "out of the box". 3. Tell us about your XSLT environment, which XSLT processor are you using, which version (1.0 or 2.0), is it running in a browser or a different environment?

Comment: i m using version 1.0 only i have written in xslt logic like for each so that i was providing all the element tags outputs at single shot

Comment: @doc Brown ... i have submitted my so far xslt please check and let me know , i m using for each in my xslt so that i m getting all values in same line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you changed your first example completely, so my first answer did not match any more to your question. That makes our discussion some kind of worthless for outsiders. Nevertheless, I adapted my solution to your new input data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select ="/swift/message/block3/tag[name='32']">
       <xsl:variable name = "first-val" select="value"/>
       <xsl:for-each select ="/swift/message/block4/tag[name='77']">
           <xsl:value-of select="concat($first-val, ',',value)"/>
<xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
       </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @doc brown thanks for your reply for that above output loop counter  will required i think so ..

Comment: @pubby: having problems to understand your comment, sorry. So is this a solution for your case, or is your situation more complex? Please clarify.

Comment: no is that solution which was provided by you it was not correct..i hope first we need get tag values of repeated one and we need to apply a loop in xslt okay let me edit the xml and xslt once i hope you can understand better boss

Comment: @doc i have modified a xml nn xslt so far i have reached please check out and let me know boss

Comment: @doc brown have you seen the above modified data i hope now you will be clear on this

Comment: @doc brown can you please check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105720/how-to-copy-the-data-of-variable-of-one-foreach-to-another-for-each-in-xslt