# how to copy the data of variable of one foreach to another for each in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

XML

```
<swift>
 <message>
     <block2 type="input">
        <messageType>102</messageType>
        <receiverAddress>BKTRUS33XBRD</receiverAddress>
        <messagePriority>N</messagePriority>     
     </block2>
     <block3>
     <tag>
     <name>32</name>
     <value>praveen</value>
     </tag>
     <tag>
     <name>42</name>
     <value>pubby</value>
     </tag>
     </block3> 
     <block4>
     <tag>
     <name>77</name>
     <value>pravz</value>
     </tag>
     <tag>
     <name>77</name>
     <value>pubbypravz</value>
     </tag>
     <tag>
     <name>99</name>
     <value>USA</value>
     </tag>
     <tag>
     <name>99</name>
     <value>UK</value>
     </tag>
     <tag>
     <name>76</name>
     <value>shanmu</value>
     </tag>
  </block4>
 </message>
</swift>
```

XSL

```
      <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

          <xsl:output method="text" />
           <xsl:param name="count" select="000001"></xsl:param >
            <xsl:template match="/">
             <xsl:for-each select ="swift/message">

             <xsl:variable name="newtype">
        <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="block2[@type = 'input']">

     <xsl:value-of  select=" concat('O', block2/messageType,block2/messagePriority )"/>,<xsl:text/>
            </xsl:when>

            <xsl:when test="block2[@type = 'output']">
     <xsl:value-of  select=" concat('I', block2/messageType,block2/messagePriority )"/>,<xsl:text/>
        </xsl:when>
           </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:for-each select ="/swift/message/block3/tag[name='32']">
    <xsl:variable name = "first-val" select="value"/>

    <xsl:for-each select ="/swift/message/block4/tag[name='77']">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($count,',',$first-val, ',',value)"/>

    <xsl:text>
        </xsl:text>
         </xsl:for-each>
       </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

i need to copy the data of which were i have declared name of "**newtype**" required the data should print in place of this bellow line

```
  <xsl:value-of select="concat($newtype,',',$first-val, ',',value)"/>
```

but above which was showing wrong because variable name was declared out of the scope so can any modify make me to reach that ouput please

the above i have hot coded this value 000001 but needed increment for every record

Expected Output

**O102N,000001,praveen,pravz,USA**

**O102N,000002, praveen,pubbypravz,UK**

Comment: can any one gimme some suggestions please .... which was data was recieved from the one of for each loop by using variable that variable should to be used in another for each loop so i can achieve my expected output i was new to this xslt so kindly please help me

Comment: Your code is unreadable because of bad indentation. If you want us to help, make your code easier to read.

Comment: @michael kay ...i hope my xml is clear and i have submitted so far what i have did xslt and i mention expected output for each record that count should be increment if any issues please let me know i will follow up you

Comment: don't know what your problems with this `concat($newtype ..` line is, but if I replace `concat($count,',',$first-val, ',',value)` in your script, it works so far. Concerning your record counter: I assume you want it to work for the case where each of the for-each loops is executed more than one cycle? That is getting hard in pure XSLT. But to discuss this, you should provide a better input data sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show me your input xml and desired output xml?

I kind of cringe a little when I see a foreach in xsl - it's a template language, and rarely needs foreach...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE stylesheet [
    <!ENTITY comma "<xsl:text>,</xsl:text>">
    <!ENTITY cr "<xsl:text>
</xsl:text>">
]>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="no" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/swift/message/block4/tag [name='77']"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="message/block4/tag [name='77']">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../../block2/@type"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="../../block2/messageType"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="../../block2/messagePriority"/>&comma;
        <xsl:number format="000001"/>&comma;
        <xsl:value-of select="../../block3/tag [name='32']/value"/>&comma;
        <xsl:value-of select="value"/>&cr;
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@type[.='input']">O</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@type[.='output']">I</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You need one row for each block4 name.  So apply a template for that block4/tag [name='77']

Then - for every one of those, select the parent elements that you need.

xsl:number will count the number of times it selected.

The ENTITY items are there to control whitespace - otherwise the formatting is crap.

No need for a foreach.  Hope this helps

Comment: @peter hancock thanks for replying .... i have modified in easier way hope now you can understand easily

Comment: @pubby - but do you understand it ;-)

Comment: @ peter hancock yes i got it thank you but here if what you have provide template xslt for any one of the tag repeatation happen in xml thats fine if suppose like tag 77 if any other tag repeated means it will wont work right ?

Comment: @pubby - no, it shouldn't make any difference.  The match rules are specific for tag=77, any other tags are simply thrown away with the catch all match=text()

Comment: @peter hancock suppose if i add one more tag like 77 in that xml then how can we give a condition in xsl:template for both 77 and 99 for your information i have edited the above xml and expected output ...can you give any suggestions please boss

Comment: @pubby - use an OR, or create an additional template to match on 99 instead.

Comment: @peter hancock ...i have taken another template but i it was wrong can yu please edit this in xslt template boss

Comment: @pubby - I'm not code for hire.  You'll need to understand the template and work through it - otherwise you'll forever be asking others to do it.  Try and work out why it doesn't work, post another question and tell us what you've tried, and then we'll get on it.

Comment: @peter hancock ...i doesnt mean that don mine me but really i have tried so i dint reached that output so i have buzz yu again anyway i have posted new one boss http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183429/how-to-check-two-or-more-conditions-in-xsl-template

Comment: @peter hancock can you please check above link which i have provided in before comment please small issue hope you understand my requirement

Answer (score 0):

**XSLT is a functional language -- among other things this means that variables are immutable** -- once given a value they cannot be changed.

**The solution** to this specific problem:

**Change**:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat($count,',',$first-val, ',',value)"/>
```

**To**:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(position(),',',$first-val, ',',value)"/>
```

**When the corrected transformation is applied to the provided XML document, the wanted result is produced**.

Comment: this will only work when the inner loop is the only one executed more than one cycle. But I guess that's not what the OP wants.

Comment: @Doc Brown: We shouldn't be guessing -- if one cannot define his problem, then he has bigger problems.