# how to check two or more conditions in xsl template

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

how to check two or more conditions in xslt

here is my xml

```
 <swift>
    <message>
        <block2 type="input">
            <messageType>102</messageType>
            <receiverAddress>BKTRUS33XBRD</receiverAddress>
            <messagePriority>N</messagePriority>     
        </block2>
        <block3>
            <tag>
                <name>32</name>
                <value>praveen</value>
            </tag>
            <tag>
                <name>42</name>
                <value>pubby</value>
            </tag>
        </block3> 
        <block4>
            <tag>
                <name>77</name>
                <value>pravz</value>
            </tag>
            <tag>
                <name>77</name>
                <value>pubbypravz</value>
            </tag>
            <tag>
                <name>99</name>
                <value>USA</value>
            </tag>
            <tag>
                <name>99</name>
                <value>UK</value>
            </tag>
            <tag>
                <name>76</name>
                <value>shanmu</value>
            </tag>
        </block4>
    </message>
</swift>
```

for this above xml we have applying this below xsl template here if any one of tag repeatation is occur xslt were working if suppose another tag were repeatation happen in xml means how can apply a logic in xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">    

    <xsl:output method="text" indent="no" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/swift/message/block4/tag [name='77']"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/swift/message/block4/tag [name='99']"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="message/block4/tag [name='77']">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../../block2/@type"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="../../block2/messageType"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="../../block2/messagePriority"/>,<xsl:text/>
        <xsl:number format="000001"/>,<xsl:text/>
        <xsl:value-of select="../../block3/tag [name='32']/value"/>,<xsl:text/>
        <xsl:value-of select="value"/>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="message/block4/tag [name='99']">
        <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
        <xsl:text>
        </xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@type[.='input']">O</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@type[.='output']">I</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected Output

**O102N,000001,praveen,pravz,USA**

**O102N,000002, praveen,pubbypravz,UK**

Comment: Are you still needing some help?

Comment: You already have the same question with a different stylesheet [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105720/how-to-copy-the-data-of-variable-of-one-foreach-to-another-for-each-in-xslt). Are you able to exactly explain what you need? May be someone can help you with the english?

Comment: @empo i dont think so ... which was same question i have changed my requirement if your willing to help me help because on my own interest i m learning this xslt okay dont discourage people...got it in last xml only one tag got repeated now here two tags were repeated i was found some difficultly to fetch data for my expected output if you know any solutions or suggestions gimme i will learn much then surely that is great of you

Comment: ok, don't want discourage you :), just try to better understand what you need. I'll have look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help you learn by example, I modified your transformation just a little:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" >
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="no" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/swift/message/block4/tag [name='77']"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="message/block4/tag [name='77']">
        <xsl:variable name="position" select="position()"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../../block2/@type"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="../../block2/messageType"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="../../block2/messagePriority"/>,<xsl:text/>
        <xsl:number format="000001"/>,<xsl:text/>
        <xsl:value-of select="../../block3/tag [name='32']/value"/>,<xsl:text/>
        <xsl:value-of select="value"/>,<xsl:text/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/swift/message/block4/tag [name='99'][position()=$position]"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="message/block4/tag [name='99']">
        <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
        <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@type[.='input']">O</xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@type[.='output']">I</xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to this document:

```
 <swift>
    <message>
        <block2 type="input">
            <messageType>102</messageType>
            <receiverAddress>BKTRUS33XBRD</receiverAddress>
            <messagePriority>N</messagePriority>
        </block2>
        <block3>
            <tag>
                <name>32</name>
                <value>praveen</value>
            </tag>
            <tag>
                <name>42</name>
                <value>pubby</value>
            </tag>
        </block3>
        <block4>
            <tag>
                <name>77</name>
                <value>pravz</value>
            </tag>
            <tag>
                <name>77</name>
                <value>pubbypravz</value>
            </tag>
            <tag>
                <name>99</name>
                <value>USA</value>
            </tag>
            <tag>
                <name>99</name>
                <value>UK</value>
            </tag>
            <tag>
                <name>76</name>
                <value>shanmu</value>
            </tag>
        </block4>
    </message>
</swift>
```

It produces the following result:

```
O102N,000001,praveen,pravz,USA
O102N,000002,praveen,pubbypravz,UK
```

Comment: @mousio thanks for replying but i m facing a small error  in this line <xsl:apply-templates select="/swift/message/block4/tag [name='99'][position()=$position]"/> "the variable or parameter 'position' is either not defined or out of it scope"

Comment: The variable `position` is declared in this line: `<xsl:variable name="position" select="position()"/>` and holds the position of the current node satisfying the match. It is referenced later in the same template – on the line you mentioned above – in the predicate to select the corresponding tag node with `name='99'` (for the tag node with `name='77'` which is currently being processed by the template).

For the *first* tag with `name='77'`, also use the *first* tag with `name='99'`; for the *second* tag with `name='77'`, also use the *second* tag with `name='99'`, and so on…

Comment: @mousio boss i dint get you can you come again please

Comment: @mousio oh okay thanks i vill do it i got it thanku so much boss

Comment: @mousio boss can you please explain number concept  <xsl:number format="000001"/> because i m getting output like in first record 000003 and second record 000014 so if i able to understand that so that i will control that for each record it should be increment

Comment: I think you need to use `<xsl:value-of select="format-number(position(), '000000')"/>`; this will give you `000001`, then `000002` and so on. The [XSLT <xsl:number> Element](http://www.w3schools.com/Xsl/el_number.asp) and the [XSLT format-number() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/XSL/func_formatnumber.asp) are not the same, but I just had not touched that part of your original transformation.